# resizing text size of label in c# .cs form

Tags: c#

I am trying to resize label in Microsoft-visual-studio-2010 ,but can't resize in the .cs design form.I want to make it big and manipulate the text's properties

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: See [Label.AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Set its AutoSize property to false!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the label name and the various properties for 'font' in the '.cs' page NOT the 'designer.cs' such as:

```
MyLabel.Font.Size = 10;
MyLabel.Bold = true;
MyLabel.Name = "Arial";
```

For more info look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fontinfo%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

If you're looking to make this a standard change for all labels then perhaps look into using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

don't make changes in the designer. Write the code to the partial class the designer.cs depends on.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",15.75F,  System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));    
    }
}
```

The value 15.75 is the size of the font as float